# How to list installed packages on Google Container Optimized OS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

Is there a way to programmatically obtain the list of installed packages on the host itself? I know there is an html file containing licenses info of both runtime and build dependencies that can be found at `/opt/google/chrome/resources/about_os_credits.html`, which [seems to be generated at build time](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform/crosutils/+/refs/heads/main/build_library/base_image_util.sh#347), but I wonder if there are other places where I can find this information in a more structured way.

Ideally, I would like to obtain the same information I can find in [flatcar-linux license.json file](https://stable.release.flatcar-linux.net/amd64-usr/current/flatcar_developer_container_licenses.json), which is also generated at build time (flatcar is also based on chromeos and uses a very similar build process, based on gentoo) but I don't know if that would be possible.

Comment: You can't install package on COS OS. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to install a package, I want to know which ones are installed

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to extract the Sofware Bill of Materials from the host

Comment: I'd like to know this information as well. It's hard to know if we're running a vulnerable version of a package, when we don't even know which packages we have.